# Generate self-signed certificate for Firefox to accept

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm setting up an internal testing network, and I want FireFox to accept my self-signed certificates. Specifically, I'm trying to configure a certificate for nginx so I can use `MyTestNetwork.dev` *and* `*.MyTestNetwork.dev`.

Here is how I'm generating my certificates:

```bash
rm rootCA.* MyTestNetwork.dev.*

# Generate rootCA
openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 4096
openssl req -x509 -new -subj="/C=US/ST=CA/O=MyTestNetwork/CN=MyTestNetwork.dev" -addext 'subjectAltName=DNS:MyTestNetwork.dev,DNS:*.MyTestNetwork.dev' -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 365 -out rootCA.crt

# Generate Server Certificates
openssl genrsa -out MyTestNetwork.dev.key 2048
openssl req -new -sha256 -key MyTestNetwork.dev.key -subj="/C=US/ST=CA/O=MyTestNetwork/CN=*.MyTestNetwork.dev" -addext 'subjectAltName=DNS:MyTestNetwork.dev,DNS:*.MyTestNetwork.dev' -out MyTestNetwork.dev.csr
openssl x509 -req -in MyTestNetwork.dev.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out MyTestNetwork.dev.crt -days 365 -sha256
```

And here is the SSL setup in nginx:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/MyTestNetwork.dev.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/MyTestNetwork.dev.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;  # about 40000 sessions
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam;

    # intermediate configuration
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds)
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0;";

    # replace with the IP address of your resolver
    resolver 127.0.0.1;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://$host$request_uri;
    }

}
```

There are two specific issues I'm facing:

1. Even when importing the `rootCA.crt` into FireFox via the "Import Certificates" setting in `about:preferences#privacy`, I get an error:

> Websites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for dns.MyTestNetwork.dev.
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

Even though that I have the correct DNS record for that server (that domain hosts the dashboard for the DNS server I'm using).

2. I cannot curl `MyTestNetwork.dev`, as I get this error:

> curl: (60) SSL: certificate subject name '*.MyTestNetwork.dev' does not match target host name 'MyTestNetwork.dev'
> More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
> establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
> how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

Even though I create the certificate with the multiple SANs.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: why dont you use LetsEnCrypt - its free of Charge?

Comment: I don't believe that subjectAltName extension will propagate from csr to crt, could you run `openssl x509 -in MyTestNetwork.dev.crt -noout -text` and see if you have the alt names?

Comment: @djdomi I'm not interested in buying the domain for my test networks :)

Comment: @jabbson That's exactly what was happening! Thank you! I had to do some more googling in order to get the correct syntax.

Comment: @jabbson+ historically `openssl x509 -req` did not copy extensions. Release 3.0.x last year, now moderately common but far from universal, has an _option_ `-copy_extensions {copy|copyall}` to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that, as @jabbson pointed out, my `subjectAltName` was not propagating from the CSR to the certificate because of my syntax. The correct syntax is:

```bash
# Generate rootCA
openssl genrsa -out config/CA/rootCA.key 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key config/CA/rootCA.key -subj="/C=RH/ST=RT/O=MyTestNetwork/CN=MyTestNetwork CA" -out config/CA/rootCA.crt
# Generate server certificate
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout config/CA/${DOMAIN}.key -subj="/C=RH/ST=RT/O=MyTestNetwork/CN=*.mytestnetwork.dev" -out config/CA/${DOMAIN}.csr
openssl x509 -req -extfile <(printf "subjectAltName=DNS:mytestnetwork.dev,DNS:*.mytestnetwork.dev") -days 365 -in config/CA/${DOMAIN}.csr -CA config/CA/rootCA.crt -CAkey config/CA/rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out config/CA/${DOMAIN}.crt
```